# Марки автомобилей

Tags: или, прописная, строчная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть с написанием частичных названий авто, например, не "Тойота-Королла", "Лада-Калина", а "приехал на "(К)королле", на "(К)калине"?

Answer (score 1):

По моим наблюдениям, на частичное наименование распространяются правила написания полных названий. То есть в общем случае пишется *"Королла"* (с прописной буквы и в кавычках). Тем не менее строгих правил нет, и разные авторы пишут по-разному.

Давайте заглянем в Нацкорпус:

> Новенькая серо-голубая «королла» стояла на обочине со спущенным
> колесом (Корецкий);
>
> Я шел мимо вереницы чиновничьих «Камри», припаркованных у старинного
> здания городской администрации (Голицын).

В обиходе же используется и вовсе написание с маленькой буквы и без кавычек.